# Unable to install libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz and mycrypt-1.0.4.gz on RHEL 8

Tags: php, linux, rhel, pecl

I am trying to install mycrypt-1.0.4 on RHEL 8 and it says mycrypt.h error Reinstall libmcrypt.
So, I am trying to install libmcrypt and I copied libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz into tmp folder. Now when I ran this command

```
       sudo dnf install /tmp/libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz
```

it throws error. What I am doing wrong here? Please correct me.

```
      Error: Unable to find a match: /tmp/libmcrypt-2.5.8
```

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to programming, or to PHP? Maybe superuser.com is a better fit for this question?

Comment: `dnf` is used for installing packages **.rpm** from the RHEL8 enabled repos. ... From the EPEL repo : `# dnf install libmcrypt-devel` provides mcrypt version 2.5.8 . ..... EPEL https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/

Comment: @KnudLarsen Where do I find this libmcrypt rpm version?

Answer (score 0):

`mcrypt-1.0.4` is a "php" module, to be installed with `pecl`.
Ref. https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt

**0** `# dnf install epel-release`
**1** `# dnf install php-devel libmcrypt-devel php-pear`
**2**. `# pecl install mcrypt`

... which will build "mcrypt-1.0.4" against php-devel and libmcrypt-devel-2.5.8
to : `/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so`